# match.fun provide error with functions defined inside functions

Tags: r

I get error when try to apply `match.fun` to the functions define within other functions.

```
x <- matrix(rnorm(10*100), nrow=100) # data sample
descStats <- function(x, stats = c("n", "min", "max", "srange", "mean", "median", "sd")) {
  n <- function(x, ...) sum(!is.na(x), ...)
  srange <- function(x, ...) max(x, ...) - min(x, ...)
  fun <- function(x) {
    result <- vapply(stats, function(z) match.fun(z)(x, na.rm=TRUE), FUN.VALUE=numeric(1))
  }
  if (is.vector(x)) {
    result <- fun(x)
  }
  if (is.matrix(x) || is.data.frame(x)) {
    result <- t(apply(x, 2, fun))
  }
  return(result)
}
descStats(x)
## Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
##   object 'n' of mode 'function' was not found
```

If I define `n` and `srange` outside of descStats function it works fine.

```
n <- function(x, ...) sum(!is.na(x), ...)
srange <- function(x, ...) max(x, ...) - min(x, ...)
descStats2 <- function(x, stats = c("n", "min", "max", "srange", "mean", "median", "sd")) {
  fun <- function(x) {
    result <- vapply(stats, function(z) match.fun(z)(x, na.rm=TRUE), FUN.VALUE=numeric(1))
  }
  if (is.vector(x)) {
    result <- fun(x)
  }
  if (is.matrix(x) || is.data.frame(x)) {
    result <- t(apply(x, 2, fun))
  }
  return(result)
}
descStats2(x)
##         n       min      max   srange        mean      median        sd
##  [1,] 100 -2.303839 2.629366 4.933205  0.03711611  0.14566523 1.0367947
##  [2,] 100 -1.968923 2.169382 4.138305 -0.03917503  0.02239458 0.9048509
##  [3,] 100 -2.365891 2.424077 4.789968 -0.08012138 -0.23515910 1.0438133
##  [4,] 100 -2.740045 2.127787 4.867832  0.03978241  0.15363449 0.9778891
##  [5,] 100 -1.598295 2.603525 4.201820  0.23796616  0.16376239 1.0428915
##  [6,] 100 -1.550385 1.684155 3.234540 -0.11114479 -0.09264598 0.8260126
##  [7,] 100 -2.438641 3.268796 5.707438  0.02948100 -0.05594740 1.0481331
##  [8,] 100 -1.716407 2.795340 4.511747  0.22463606  0.16296613 0.9555129
##  [9,] 100 -2.359165 1.975993 4.335158 -0.33321888 -0.17580933 0.9784788
## [10,] 100 -2.139267 2.838986 4.978253  0.15540182  0.07803265 1.0149671
```

Another way it's use `eval(call(FUN, args))`. For instance.

```
descStats3 <- function(x, stats = c("n", "min", "max", "srange", "mean", "median", "sd")) {
  n <- function(x, ...) sum(!is.na(x), ...)
  srange <- function(x, ...) max(x, ...) - min(x, ...)
  fun <- function(x) {
    result <- vapply(stats, function(z) eval(call(z, x, na.rm=TRUE)), FUN.VALUE=numeric(1))
  }
  if (is.vector(x)) {
    result <- fun(x)
  }
  if (is.matrix(x) || is.data.frame(x)) {
    result <- t(apply(x, 2, fun))
  }
  return(result)
}
descStats3(x)
##         n       min      max   srange        mean      median        sd
##  [1,] 100 -2.303839 2.629366 4.933205  0.03711611  0.14566523 1.0367947
##  [2,] 100 -1.968923 2.169382 4.138305 -0.03917503  0.02239458 0.9048509
##  [3,] 100 -2.365891 2.424077 4.789968 -0.08012138 -0.23515910 1.0438133
##  [4,] 100 -2.740045 2.127787 4.867832  0.03978241  0.15363449 0.9778891
##  [5,] 100 -1.598295 2.603525 4.201820  0.23796616  0.16376239 1.0428915
##  [6,] 100 -1.550385 1.684155 3.234540 -0.11114479 -0.09264598 0.8260126
##  [7,] 100 -2.438641 3.268796 5.707438  0.02948100 -0.05594740 1.0481331
##  [8,] 100 -1.716407 2.795340 4.511747  0.22463606  0.16296613 0.9555129
##  [9,] 100 -2.359165 1.975993 4.335158 -0.33321888 -0.17580933 0.9784788
## [10,] 100 -2.139267 2.838986 4.978253  0.15540182  0.07803265 1.0149671
identical(descStats2(x), descStats3(x))
## [1] TRUE
```

Why `descStats` not work?

Comment: I like the reproducible example, but a more minimal example would be `fun <- function(x) n <- sum; match.fun('n')(x)`. Just in case others are looking through this.

Comment: @nograpes: I agree but I decided to bring the real function from my work as an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is a scope problem. Looking in the code of match.fun you get the answer.

`match.fun` scope  is the  `envir <- parent.frame(2)`

`get` scope is  in the     `envir = as.environment(-1) = parent.frame(1)`

I think we can't pass the envir as an argument.
One solution is to use get as presented by @nograpes ( unsafe) or to hack `match.fun` and change

`envir <- parent.frame(2)` to  `envir <- parent.frame(1)`

Answer (score 5):

It's relatively easy (and illustrative) to write your own version of `match.fun`.  I've called my function `fget` to indicate that it's a version of `get` specifically designed for functions, and hence obeys the regular scoping rules for functions.  (If you're not sure what they are, think about this code: `c <- 10; c(c, 5)`)

```
#' Find a function with specified name.
#'
#' @param name length one character vector giving name
#' @param env environment to start search in.
#' @examples
#' c <- 10
#' fget("c")
fget <- function(name, env = parent.frame()) {
  if (identical(env, emptyenv())) {
    stop("Could not find function called ", name, call. = FALSE)
  }

  if (exists(name, env, inherits = FALSE) && is.function(env[[name]])) {
    env[[name]]
  } else {
    fget(name, parent.env(env))
  }
}
```

The implementation is as a straightforward recursive function: the base case is the `emptyenv()`, the eventual ancestor of every environment, and for each environment along the stack of parents, we check to see that both an object called `name` exists, and that it is a function.

It works in the simple test case provided by @nograpes because the environment defaults to the calling environment:

```
fun <- function(x) {
  n <- sum
  fget('n')(x)
}
fun(10)
# [1] 10
```

Answer (score 1):

For reasons I don't completely understand yet, if you use `get` instead of `match.fun`, everything works fine.

```
x <- matrix(rnorm(10*100), nrow=100) # data sample
descStats <- function(x, stats = c("n", "min", "max", "srange", "mean", "median", "sd")) {
  n <- function(x, ...) sum(!is.na(x), ...)
  srange <- function(x, ...) max(x, ...) - min(x, ...)
  fun <- function(x) {
    # get added here.
    result <- vapply(stats, function(z) get(z)(x, na.rm=TRUE), FUN.VALUE=numeric(1))
  }
  if (is.vector(x)) {
    result <- fun(x)
  }
  if (is.matrix(x) || is.data.frame(x)) {
    result <- t(apply(x, 2, fun))
  }
  return(result)
}
descStats(x)
```