# Problem with 'match.arg()' inside 'outer()' function

Tags: r, function, scope, vectorization, apply

### Background/Problem

I am trying to use the [`outer()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/outer) function to apply a function on all the pairwise combinations of two vectors as arguments. In my case one of the inputs is a character vector that should serve as arguments to an inner function (`cor()`) that will need to run `match.arg()` on it.

### Example 1 (it works)

This works fine when the inner function doesn't require this such as with `paste()`.

```r
# define function to test
f1 <- function(method, vec_len){
  paste(method, vec_len)
}

# define inputs to test
methods <- c("pearson", "spearman", "kendall")
vec_lens <- 33:35

# outer runs fine
outer(methods, vec_lens, f1)
#>      [,1]          [,2]          [,3]         
#> [1,] "pearson 33"  "pearson 34"  "pearson 35" 
#> [2,] "spearman 33" "spearman 34" "spearman 35"
#> [3,] "kendall 33"  "kendall 34"  "kendall 35"
```

### Example 2 (it doesn't work)

However when the inner function needs to run `match.arg()` on the input this fails:

```r
# function that parses string with match.arg fails
f2 <- function(method, vec_len){
  x <- runif(vec_len, 0, 10)
  y <- x + rnorm(vec_len)
  
  cor(x, y, method = method)
}

# outer fails on match.arg within cor()
outer(methods, vec_lens, f2)
#> Error in match.arg(method): 'arg' must be of length 1
```

### My research

From the research I've done ([1](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/match.arg), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183766/match-fun-provide-error-with-functions-defined-inside-functions), [3](https://colinfay.me/r-language-definition/functions.html)) it looks like this might be related to the scoping of the inner function being unable to access the global environment but I'm not sure and don't know how to fix it.

---

### BTW

I know the code is fine because I can get the result with a loop:

```r
# desired result by loop
out <- list()
for (method in methods) {
  for (j in seq_along(vec_lens)) {
    out[[method]][[j]] <- f2(method, vec_lens[j])
    names(out[[method]])[j] <- vec_lens[j]
  }
}
do.call(rbind, out)
#>          33        34        35       
#> pearson  0.9351946 0.9491004 0.9516057
#> spearman 0.9067513 0.9315508 0.9456583
#> kendall  0.8371212 0.8146168 0.7983193
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can wrap with `Vectorize`

```
set.seed(24)
outer(methods, vec_lens, FUN = Vectorize(f2))
       [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.9060101 0.9661931 0.9572807
[2,] 0.9542112 0.9495798 0.9490196
[3,] 0.8863636 0.8680927 0.7983193
```

which gives the same output as `for` loop (except for the `dimnames`)

```
> set.seed(24)
> out <- list()
> for (method in methods) {
+   for (j in seq_along(vec_lens)) {
+     out[[method]][[j]] <- f2(method, vec_lens[j])
+     names(out[[method]])[j] <- vec_lens[j]
+   }
+ }
> do.call(rbind, out)
         33        34        35       
pearson  0.9060101 0.9309473 0.9637686
spearman 0.9532086 0.9254393 0.9526611
kendall  0.8257576 0.8074866 0.7983193
```

Comment: Thanks that's super helpful! So it looks like the issue is whether the inner function is vectorized? Also I can solve the `dimnames` issue by providing named vectors as the input.

Comment: @DanAdams It is related to the replication steps in the `outer` code i.e. `Browse[2]> 
debug: FUN <- match.fun(FUN)
Browse[2]> 
debug: Y <- rep(Y, rep.int(length(X), length(Y)))
Browse[2]> 
debug: if (length(X)) X <- rep(X, times = ceiling(length(Y)/length(X)))
Browse[2]> 
debug: X <- rep(X, times = ceiling(length(Y)/length(X)))
Browse[2]> 
debug: FUN(X, Y, ...)
Browse[2]> 
Error in match.arg(method) : 'arg' must be of length 1`

Comment: This is also described in [rfaq](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-does-outer_0028_0029-behave-strangely-with-my-function_003f)